# Prepared Statements in MariDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm fiddling around on my test database, learning how to set it all up. 
I'm using PHP and PDO objects to access my database and get Data from it. 
I'm also using prepared statements against MySQL Injections.

This is the code I'm using:

```
mainframe();

function mainframe(){
  $connection = establishConnectionToDatabase();
  $result = getData($connection);
  //var_dump($result);
  //echo json_encode($result);
  echo $result;
}

function getData($connection){
  $fetch = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_tbl");
  $fetch->execute();
  $result = $fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $result;
}

function establishConnectionToDatabase(){
  try
  {
     $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foundationtests',
           'verwalter','test');
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
        echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  return $connection;
}
```

The table Im Accessing looks like this (see screenshot):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6yl6.jpg

When executing the above code, I'm only getting back

**Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **D:\foundationtests\src\assets\php\test.php** on line **12**
Array

I already tried out without prepared statements and it worked. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: It has nothing to do with prepared statements. `$result` is an array and you can't echo arrays.

Comment: You can however for example var_dump them, which apparently you already had in there earlier, and then commented out … why?

Comment: @misorude 
Thanks! Well, I'm super confused now since I echoed lots of arrays in the past via echo json_encode($data); , in another tool. But there, I didnt use prepared statements to fetch the data there, so maybe this has something to do with it?.

Comment: You can't echo an array directly. json_encode accepts an array for its output. To output a standard array you need to use print_r() or var_dump()

Comment: _“since I echoed lots of arrays in the past via echo json_encode($data)”_ - then you didn’t actually echo arrays, you echoed _strings_, because that is what json_encode returns.

Comment: @misorude thanks, this did the trick for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is fine, you can't echo an array.

As you're returning an array, try this

```
function getData($connection){
  $fetch = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_tbl");
  $fetch->execute();
  $result = $fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return (object)$result;
}
```

This will return your value as an object. Then you can echo whatever value using `$result->user_id` for example.

You can learn more about objects [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

**UPDATE**

As has been pointed out, you can also just make it return as an object by change the 4th line from `$result = $fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to `$result = $fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`, and then changing the last line back to `return $result;`

Comment: Or you could just ask PDO to return an object instead of associative array.